# Append a string after the QUESTION MARK sign

Tags: javascript

I have a string URL. i need to append the following string at a given position.

```
http://site:8080/Pic/User/Snap?x=hi
```

How can i append the string `id=12&` so it looks like follows:

```
http://site:8080/Pic/User/Snap?id=12&x=hi
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://site:8080/Pic/User/Snap?x=hi";
var pos = url.indexOf('?') + 1;
var newUrl = url.substr(0, pos) + "id=12&" + url.substr(pos);
```

You can find the position(index) of `?` with `indexOf()` function. Then `substr` the string before and after `?`. Now you can concatenate the strings again with `id=12&` in the middle of them.